# Could Raft elect a leader with uncommitted log?

Tags: raft, leader

Suppose a cluster of 5 nodes(ABCDE), node-A is elected leader at the beginning, and while leader-A issues AppendEntries RPCs to the follower(BCDE) to replicate log entry(log-X)，only node-B receives and returns success, at this point leader-A crashes.

If node C(or D or E) wins the next leader election then everything's fine, because only node B has log-X, and that means log-X is not committed.

My question is, could node-B (which has the highest term and longest log) win the next leader election? If so, will node-B spread log-X to other nodes?

Comment: In your original question, if A returns the Client the fail response of log-X. Now the B win the leader and has the log-X, how to deal with log-X, according to my understanding the log should be discard because the old leader A return the fail response of log-X. If Leader B commit the log-x, then it will cause client data inconsistency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes B could win the election, if it does become leader then the first thing it does it to create a log entry with the new term in its log, and start replicating its log to all the followers. As B's log includes log-X, if all goes well, eventually the log-X entry will be replicated & considered committed.

If node C wins the election, then when it becomes leader, it won't have the log-X entry, and it'll end up overwriting that entry on Node B.

See section 5.4.2 of the [raft paper](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) for more details.

Also this means you can't treat failure as meaning the attempted entry definitely doesn't exist, only that the caller doesn't know the outcome. Section 8 has some suggestions for handling this.

Comment: thanks a lot, I still have a question: if leader-A received request to commit log-Y before A crashed, and it committed it by replicating log-Y to CDE(not B), now CDE's log is mmmY and B's log is mmm. And while leader-A replicating next log(log-X) to other nodes, only B receives and A crashes. Now B's log is mmmX, CDE's log is mmmY. B could still win the next election cause its log is up-to-date(index=4, term=A, same as others). But this could overwrite CDE's log to mmmX, wouldn't it be a problem because log-Y is considered committed?

Comment: replication works backwards so b can't end up in that state.

Comment: also append entries includes the index number, so it'll spot that there's a hole where Y was suposed to be.

Comment: right, node B can be either mmmYX or mmm, can't be mmmX. thx~